# Excel password protected Add-in, found out all public function

Tags: excel, add-in, password-protection

Is there a way to found out all the public function in a password protected add-in? Is it possible I can find out through the buttons that the add-in places on the ribbon in excel 2010?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The public functions should be listed in the "Insert function" wizard, in the "Custom" category. The public subs should appear in the "Customize the Ribbon" section of Excel's options, in the "Macros" category.

Comment: Custom functions can also be coded to appear in the categories.